# Tilemill export in mbtiles data size

Tags: hosting, gis, tilemill

I'd like to know what is the data size necessary if I want to generate a map of the whole world, with every zoom level available with tilemill.

I found that it was around 100mo for 8 level zoom [there](http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/general-questions/16630-how-to-minimize-motile-file-size-for-offline-map-comparing-mbtiles-from-ios-framework-v-tilemill-export).

The sister question is what can I host with the [basic plan from Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/plans/) that includes 250mo data upload. Is it useless, or is there anychance of doing something out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer by trying to export my map in TileMill :

To get the whole world, starting from zoom 0, if you play with zoom max, here are the given estimations :

```
- Zoom 15 à 22 ==> 1000 Gb+ 
- Zoom 12 à 14 ==> 100 Gb+ 
- Zoom 11 ==> 10 Gb+
- Zoom 10 ==> 1 Gb+
- Zoom 9 ==> 100mb
- Zoom 8 ==> 10mb
- Zoom 7 ==> 1mb
- Zoom <7 ==> <1mb
```

Answer (score 1):

Each level generally increases the data size by a factor of 4 - unless your layers are becoming less complex.  For instance, if you start to have single color tiles - they use less disk space and you can have an increase as low as a factor of 3.